Edge function in cs50 filters pset
I’ve been working on the cs50 filters assignment. All the other ones have had pretty small issues with easy fixes, but this one if completely not working.
This project’s intended purpose is to detect “edges” in an image using something called the Sobel operator. It’s pretty hard to explain, But here’s a link to the cs50 article that explains it pretty well (scroll down to the “image filtering” section and the subheading “edges”).
Here is my code (explanation below):
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int gx[9] = {-1, 0, 1, -2, 0, 2, -1, 0, 1};
    int gy[9] = {-1, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1};
    int blue_sum_x = 0;
    int red_sum_x = 0;
    int green_sum_x = 0;
    int blue_sum_y = 0;
    int red_sum_y = 0;
    int green_sum_y = 0;
    int count;
    RGBTRIPLE image_tmp[height][width];
    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
        {
            image_tmp[h][w] = image[h][w];
        }
    }
    for (int h = -1; h <= height; h++)
    {
        image_tmp[h][-1].rgbtRed = 0;
        image_tmp[h][-1].rgbtGreen = 0;
        image_tmp[h][-1].rgbtBlue = 0;
        image_tmp[h][width].rgbtRed = 0;
        image_tmp[h][width].rgbtGreen = 0;
        image_tmp[h][width].rgbtBlue = 0;
    }
    for (int w = -1; w <= width; w++)
    {
        image_tmp[-1][w].rgbtRed = 0;
        image_tmp[-1][w].rgbtGreen = 0;
        image_tmp[-1][w].rgbtBlue = 0;
        image_tmp[height][w].rgbtRed = 0;
        image_tmp[height][w].rgbtGreen = 0;
        image_tmp[height][w].rgbtBlue = 0;
    }

    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
        {
            count = 0;
                for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = -1; j < 2; j++)
                    {
                        {
                            blue_sum_x += gx[count] * image_tmp[h + i][w + j].rgbtBlue;
                            red_sum_x += gx[count] * image_tmp[h + i][w + j].rgbtRed;
                            green_sum_x += gx[count] * image_tmp[h + i][w + j].rgbtGreen;
                            blue_sum_y += gy[count] * image_tmp[h + i][w + j].rgbtBlue;
                            red_sum_y += gy[count] * image_tmp[h + i][w + j].rgbtRed;
                            green_sum_y += gy[count] * image_tmp[h + i][w + j].rgbtGreen;
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            image[h][w].rgbtBlue = round(sqrt(pow(blue_sum_x, 2) + pow(blue_sum_y, 2)));
            if (round(sqrt(pow(blue_sum_x, 2) + pow(blue_sum_y, 2))) > 255)
            {
                image[h][w].rgbtBlue = 255;
            }
            image[h][w].rgbtRed = round(sqrt(pow(red_sum_x, 2) + pow(red_sum_y, 2)));
            if (round(sqrt(pow(red_sum_x, 2) + pow(red_sum_y, 2))) > 255)
            {
                image[h][w].rgbtRed = 255;
            }
            image[h][w].rgbtGreen = round(sqrt(pow(green_sum_x, 2) + pow(green_sum_y, 2)));
            if (round(sqrt(pow(green_sum_x, 2) + pow(green_sum_y, 2))) > 255)
            {
                image[h][w].rgbtGreen = 255;
            }
        }
    }
}

EXPLANATION: The function takes in 3 parameters:

The height of the image
The width of the image
An array of data type RGBTRIPLE representing the image, where each part of they array is a pixel and has 3 attributes: rgbtRed, rgbtGreen, and rgbtBlue, all of which represent their respective color levels in that specific pixel.

The first thing I do here is initialize a bunch of variables to 0, and create 2 arrays of numbers, both of which represent the Sobel operators. Then, I create a duplication of the image (image_tmp) that I can reference when the first image is only half-transformed. Next, I create a 1-pixel black border around image_tmp. This is so that I don’t have to check for edge and corner cases and is mostly just for efficiency’s sake.
Now comes the most important step. I iterate over each pixel, and for each pixel I iterate over a 3x3 square centered at that pixel. For each pixel in the square, I add its color amounts (multiplied by the Sobel operator  for that pixel) to its respective sum. Then I add 1 to the count variable, which just keeps track of how far through I am on the sobel operator arrays (gx and gy). Then I do the math for each pixel (square the x and y sums for each color, add them together, and take the square root). Finally, I check to make sure it’s capped at 255.
When I ran this code for the first time with an image, the image it spit out looked like tv static, with random colors everywhere. I thought that this may have been because I forgot to cap colors at 255, but when I added that in, the program would only return white. At that time, my function was extremely inefficient, and on each loop iteration, I checked if it was an edge or a corner, and then depending on where it was, I would only use certain values of i and j. I’m still not really sure why it didn’t work, but it didn’t, so I altered my code to what is written above (I added in a black border and then just ran all of the pixels like they were middle pixels. Now, my program returns a  mostly unchanged image, but with a strange 1-pixel colored stripe across the top, usually a bright purplish-blue.
I know my code seems really long, but it’s a lot of repetition (x and y directions, RGB individual colors). I’m sure it’s not the most efficient, but if I tried to make it more efficient I think it would make less sense.
If anyone sees any issues, it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

I don't get why for (int h = -1; h <= height; h++) is used to index the array out of bounds. Is it your attempt to create a black border?

Start with a tiny bitmap, say, 3x3. That's small enough that you can run the Sobel operator with pencil and paper. Do the results match what your program does? If not, go through your program with a debugger step by step to find where it diverges from your hand calculations.

I think I see a lot of out-of-bounds array access like image_tmp[-1][w].rgbtRed = 0; and image_tmp[h + i][w + j] (when h == 0 and i == -1 for example). I'm pretty sure you don't want to do that because its causing undefined behavior. Also can you post the RGBTRIPLE definition?

I used the same method you're using to solve the problem. I think making gx and gy 2D arrays will make this problem easier to solve.
int gx[3][3] = {{-1, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}};

int gy[3][3] = {{-1, -2, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}};

Also recommend walking through it on paper. Message me if you need any help implementing it!
